Can't open Jupyter notebook, which reports an error : "Cannot import name 'NOTHING' from 'attr' "
After installing Anaconda, I want to open the jupyter notebook, but I can't open it when I click it directly, and I get an error with a command line statement, which is very confusing. I've re-uninstalled ananconda and reinstalled several times and it's all like this.
ImportError: cannot import name 'NOTHING' from 'attr' (C:\Users\zhaoxin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\attr.py)
At the same time, I can't open ananconda navigator either，, which reports an error : “AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'”.
(base) C:\Users\zhaoxin>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 21, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config import CONF, LINUX, LOCKFILE, MAC, PIDFILE, UBUNTU
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import preferences
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\preferences.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import structures
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\config\structures.py", line 33, in <module>
    @attr.s(auto_attribs=True, eq=False, frozen=True, slots=True)
     ^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'```
I have tried to update attr,but it didn't work.
Installing anaconda maybe is successful?

conda --version
conda 24.1.2
I've re-uninstalled ananconda and reinstalled several times and it's all like this.
What can I do?Please give me some advice!Thank you!


Are you cleaning things up before you reinstall? I see you stating, "re-uninstalled ananconda and reinstalled several times". But that doesn't make it clear. You seem to have a bad install and need to really work to clean things up before just reinstalling.
